# Is it possible to create a config system with bash?

Tags: bash

I was wondering if it's possible to create a config system with Bash. See my Python script below for an example;

So this is basically a config system that I use in my Python scripts, I called it `config.py`;

```py
server_list = {
    "server1": {
        "ip": "127.0.0.1",
        "ssh_port": "22",
        "username": "root",
        "pass": "pass123",
    },
    "server2": {
        "ip": "127.0.0.2",
        "ssh_port": "22",
        "username": "root",
        "pass": "pass123",
    },
}
```

Then I can use this config file to connect to my servers with my main script *(just an example tho)*, `app.py`

I wonder if a similar thing is possible in Bash?

Comment: Have you looked at Yaml format?

Comment: Or JSON, or XML. I would go with JSON because it is easy to manipulate with `jq` and reasonably compact, as well as fairly close to what you have already. Voting to close as unclear and too broad, though; it's really not clear what this config snippet actually does, or what would be a satisfactory solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

[Bash itself is a terrible language for dealing with nested structures](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashWeaknesses) such as JSON, YAML and XML. It is a Turing complete language so it is definitely *possible,* but I would strongly recommend against it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. What would you suggest?

Comment: Python, Ruby, Java, Rust, Haskell, LISP, even Perl.